# Border-radius на IE9 и ниже

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Не работает border-radius у IE9 и ниже. Кто как решал эту проблему? Помогите с советами. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: дикий свежак из 2009 года (aka первая ссылка в гугле): https://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что у вас с ИЕ9, но там border-radius должен работать идеально.

Для ИЕ <= 9 есть [PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: PIE у меня не сработало звчем то! =(

Мне ведь там только .htc файл подключать нужно? Или js файлы тоже???

Answer (score 1):

Допустим есть файл index.html, а также папка css, в которой находиться style.css

В папку css - PIE.htc

В файле style.css - для подключения PIE

```
.classname{ 
    behavior: url('css/PIE.htc');
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative; 
}
```

or

```
.classname{ 
    behavior: url('css/PIE.htc');
    zoom: 1;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

как-то так

Comment: во-во, я тоже заметил, что для работоспособности pie нужно элементу дать  zoom: 1 и какое то позиционирование

Comment: да так и есть